# How can I configure Android so that the alarm emit some sound when I'm on hold on a call?

Tags: audio, calls, android-11, alarm, google-pixel-6

I use Android 11 with pixel 6. By default, the alarm doesn't emit any sound when I'm on hold on a call. How can I change that?

Example of alarm ringing silently while a call has been put on hold:

[image]